# Sorting all possible combinations

Tags: list, c#-4.0

i´m trying to sort a list of combinations in a specific way.
Consider the numbers 1-6 as teams, if every team can play on time against each other team we got this list as possible matches:

```
12 23 34 45 56
13 24 35 46 
14 25 36        
15 26           
16
```

So now what i want is something like "matchdays":

```
12    13    14    15    16
34    46    26    24    23
56    25    35    36    45
```

As you can see after each block every team has one game, two games, ...
I could´n get a algorithm to sort the list this from:

`12 13  14  15  16  23  24  25  26  34  35  36  45  46  56`

to

`12 34  56  13  46  25  14  26  35  15  24  36  16  23  45`

Additional:
With odd team numbers the way to create matchdays gets even worse because you have to leave on team out for the day:

```
12 23 34 45
13 24 35    
14 25       
15  

12    23    14    24    25
34    45    35    15    13
```

In the first block 5 is not playing in the second block 1 ist not playing....

Thank you for any help or ideas regarding this problem in c# with .net 4 possibly using Linq to manipulate the list.

SOLUTION:

Round-robin tournament
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Round-robin_tournament
[Round Robin Tournament algorithm in C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1293058/round-robin-tournament-algorithm-in-c)

Comment: I haven't read your question in depth yet, but can you make it a little more clear which of the many different outputs and formatting methods you've suggested is the one you want?

Comment: Its not about the output, the numbers are just for the explanation.

Comment: This is called a round-robin tournament for anyone that wants to Google.

Comment: Thanks Gilbert Le Blanc! Thats it, can you answer my question so that i can accept this as the right answer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You dont really need to sort this (from what I can see).

All you need to do is create 'sets' of 3 items, where an item is {A,B} for the 2 teams.

So for the start, pick any random item (and remove from list of all combinations), then you have say: {1,3}.  Then choose another random number (and remove) where {A,B} != 1 or 3 for both A and B. The last step is easy, as you only have 2 options left. Pick any valid option, remove from list.  Repeat 4 more times.

Comment: Problem is: he will find {12, 34, 56} in the next round {13, 24, x}. At x the only possible solution is again 56!

Comment: @Gpx: You could perhaps discard that one, and try the next.

Comment: In this case there is no next!