# Algorithm for pairing tourney players

Tags: c#, algorithm

I am looking for an algorithm that will pair 8 players in a double round robin tournament such that no player will play the same side twice consecutively, that is, every player playing **home** during a round must play **away** the next round and vice versa.

Eight players in round robin must play seven rounds of four fixtures each in order for every player to play against every other player, so for a double round robin, each play will play as **home** and as **away** against every other player resulting in fourteen rounds of four fixtures each.

I generated the raw unsorted collection of fixtures that gives balanced **home-away** distribution using the code below:

```
for (int x = 1; x <= 8; x++)
        {
            for (int y = 8; y > x; y--)
            {
                PairThese(x, y);
            }
        }
```

The PairThese() methods creates a fixture with player x playing home against player y and creates another fixture with player y playing home against player x to complete the double round robin.

The problem, like aforementioned is how to arrange the fixtures such that each player will always play as home in a round and as away in the next or vice versa

Comment: [Round Robin Tournament algorithm in C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1293058/round-robin-tournament-algorithm-in-c-sharp) see how you go

Comment: Doesn't work. Different issue